# Find duplicate position of two arrays, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have two arrays, one `oldArray` and one `newArray`. They are both flat and have the same length. I want a function that checks if the `newArray` has a duplicate, and I want the position that contains the duplicate compared to in the `oldArray`.

Example:

```
var oldArr = ['abc', null, 'dd', null, 'cc]
var newArr = ['abc', null, 'dd', 'dd', 'cc]
```

The `dd` is the duplicate and it happened at position 3 compared to the old array. Is there any smart way to do this? Ok to use underscore/lodash in answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Do you count position from 0 or from 1?

Comment: @lonesomeday Yes, for hours

Comment: @user44, from 0

Comment: @PerStröm Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "position 3 compared to the old array"? If there is a duplicate value withing `newArr`, the position (index) of that duplicate has nothing to do with `oldArr`, does it? Or, if you are looking for the position (index) of the matching value in `oldArr` -- it should be 2, not 3. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the `newArr` using `Array#reduce`, and store the position of every element, that is found on another index in `oldArr`:

```js
var oldArr = ['abc', null, 'dd', null, 'cc'];
var newArr = ['abc', null, 'dd', 'dd', 'cc'];

var duplicates = newArr.reduce(function(d, e, i) {
  var oldIndex = oldArr.indexOf(e);
  oldIndex !== -1 && oldIndex !== i && d.push(i);
  
  return d;
}, []);
              
console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function find(oldA, newA){
   var ret = {};
   for(var i = 0; i < newA.length; i++){
      if(newA.match(newA[i]).lenth > 1){
        ret.value = newA[i]; res.pos = newA[i] === old[i]?newA.lastIndexOf(ret.value)?i;}
 return ret;
 }

   var res = find(oldArray, newArray)
```